# Import Polygon Into Google My Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

### Background

I have a Google Map, creating with the JavaScript API.. I have a set of polygons which are overlays on the map.

These polygons started out as KML files, but have been converted to encoded polygons. Encoding Algorithm information: **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm**

**Example:**

```
oosrFrdygOh_sJpchBoog@y{lPyylHtcA_t\praM
```

This is a 4 point polygon in Ohio.

### Question

My question is, is there a way to import these into Google My Maps? I'd like to import these so that I can edit them.

Comment: Do you still have the KML files?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm working with a pre-existing app and dataset. The original developer didn't save the KML files after he encoded them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, an encoded polygon cannot be imported. For a shape to be imported to My Maps, it must first be converted to a KML file.

BlueCollar laid out the first step, which is to use Google's encoding API to decode the encoded shapes into Lat/Lng pairs.

```
var encodedPath = 'oosrFrdygOh_sJpchBoog@y{lPyylHtcA_t\praM';
var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);
```

For the example encoded value, which would return:

```
(39.91816, -85.33082),(38.013470000000005, -85.86915),(38.22091, -83.01270000000001),(39.76632, -83.02369),(39.91816, -85.33082)
```

Those pairs then need to be inserted into a KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Test Shape</name>
    <Polygon>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
            -85.33082,39.91816
            -85.86915,38.01347
            -83.01270000000001,38.22091
            -83.02369,39.76632
            -85.33082,39.91816
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

The KML file can then be imported.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `decodePath()` on the encoded string, i.e.:

`let encodedPath = 'oosrFrdygOh_sJpchBoog@y{lPyylHtcA_t\praM';
 let path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);`

Comment: If I do this, I get a set of pairs such as: `(39.91816, -85.33082),(38.013470000000005, -85.86915),(38.22091, -83.01270000000001),(39.76632, -83.02369),(39.91816, -85.33082)`. I've tried putting this into an Excel doc to import to My Maps and it just throws errors.

Comment: These are all valid coordinates in the United States mid west. I am not sure what you mean by putting these into an excel document, but the answer to how to decode these was provided and you can always just copy these directly into a KML (though your question said you started with a KML, so I'm not sure why you'd want to go KML->encryptedCoords->KML again...) or just use them immediately in subsequent javascript since they are available.

Comment: The question was "is there a way to import these into Google My Maps".

Comment: Can he just take the decoded pairs and put them in a .csv and import them per [Google Import Info](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?hl=en) ?

Comment: That would create many individual points rather than single polygons. The points first need to be converted into a KML polygon.

Comment: Then your solution should be right (and marked as such)